# C# How to open a webpage and click a button

Tags: c#, click, html

I have a problem to solve.

A button has this code:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate(link, true);
wb.Document.GetElementById(idname).InvokeMember("click");
```

I have a NullReferenceException on the GetElementById because when I reach it, the page is "white". If I comment the GetElementById, the page is opened correctly.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a timer with few seconds delay and can invoke click.

Comment: Hi Anand, thanks for the answer. I suppose it is not a problem of delay. Because if I debug, the page still "white" until the last "}" of my code. It is a particular behaviour, because after the instruction the document still null, but if I ran the application for entire the page load correctly. 
I do not know if I explained well

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
private WebBrowser _wb = new WebBrowser();

public FormMain()
{
    _wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: WebBrowser is intended to be used as a visual control - you wouldn't typically construct it like this and use it directly in code. Make sure you create a Form with that control on it.

Comment: I had to use the visual control, now it works fine. Thanks!